# Find numbers not used in a column

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

How can I find in a column filled with numbers, the ones that are *not* used.

Table_A:

```
'id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
'client_code' int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,    
'client_name' varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
```

```
INSERT INTO Table_A ('client_code','client_name') VALUES (1,'Bob');    
INSERT INTO Table_A ('client_code','client_name') VALUES (2,'Anna');    
INSERT INTO Table_A ('client_code','client_name') VALUES (5,'Jim');    
INSERT INTO Table_A ('client_code','client_name') VALUES (6,'Tom');    
INSERT INTO Table_A ('client_code','client_name') VALUES (10,'Mattew');
```

If I `SELECT 'client_code' FROM Table_A` the output will be `1,2,5,6,10`. How can I have the numbers that are not used?

```
(3,4,7,8,9,11,12...)
```

Comment: upto which number you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's *missing*, you can compare to a *complete* list.
There is no **row generator** in MySQL (like [`generate_series()` in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html)), but various surrogates are floating around. [Like this one in the MySQL forums.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,314962,315574#msg-315574)

Helper table to provide numbers from `0-9`:

```
CREATE TABLE int10 (i INT);
INSERT INTO int10 VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Building on that, generate a *complete* range of numbers:

```
SELECT i1.i * 10 + i0.i AS client_code
FROM   int10 i1, int10 i0    -- works up to 99, extend as needed
WHERE (i1.i * 10 + i0.i) < (SELECT max(client_code) FROM table_a) -- limit to actual max
```

Now you can generate the list of missing numbers, exactly as requested:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(n.client_code ORDER BY n.client_code) AS missing_codes
FROM  (
  SELECT i1.i * 10 + i0.i AS client_code
  FROM   int10 i1, int10 i0    -- works up to 99, extend as needed
  WHERE (i1.i * 10 + i0.i) < (SELECT max(client_code) FROM table_a)
  ) n
LEFT   JOIN table_a  a USING (client_code)
WHERE  a.client_code IS NULL;
```

Key elements are the [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) and the aggregate function [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).
To get full list of codes / names including missing codes, as may be your ultimate goal:

```
SELECT n.client_code, a.client_name
FROM  (
  SELECT i1.i * 10 + i0.i AS client_code
  FROM   int10 i1, int10 i0    -- works up to 99, extend as needed
  WHERE (i1.i * 10 + i0.i) < (SELECT max(client_code) FROM table_a)
  ) n
LEFT   JOIN table_a  a USING (client_code)
ORDER  BY n.client_code;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0de4/11)

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure as below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckNotUsedNos(in v1 int)
BEGIN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `incr`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `incr` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
);
  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    INSERT incr VALUES (NULL);
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;

Select Id from `incr` 
where Id not in 
(select client_code from `Client`);

END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Call as you would like to have your parameter.
(Just trying with 11 )

```
call CheckNotUsedNos(11);
```

And I got below results

```
ID
3
4
7
8
9
11
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96d82b/1)**

Answer (score -3):

You can have it by the difference between  "rownumber"  generated for all the rows in the `Table_A` and `client_code`:

```
select * from (
  SELECT @ROWNUMBER:=@ROWNUMBER+1 AS COL FROM Table_A
  JOIN    (SELECT @ROWNUMBER := 0) D) B
where B.COL not in (select client_code from Table_A);
```

your `client_code` values have to start from 1 and increment by one.

Comment: No, this will only return two rows with 3 and 4: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7beda/1)**